# Angular 2 - some Primeng images not showing up

Tags: angular, angular2-template, primeng

I am using priming library to implement functionalities like calendar , data table etc but some images are not showing up :

This is what I have in angular-cli.json:

```
 "styles": [
        "styles.css",
         "../node_modules/primeui/themes/overcast/theme.css",
         "../node_modules/primeui/primeui-ng-all.min.css"
      ],
```

app.module.ts

```
 imports: [
...
    DataTableModule,
    CalendarModule
  ],
```

Here is what I see in grid and calendar :

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you need to check network tab in developer tools, and look for missing images. After that put it images in folder that required in path

Comment: I don't see any missing images in developer tools ...

Comment: Maybe it fonts or svg? Nothing missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
  "styles.css",
         "../node_modules/primeui/themes/overcast/theme.css",
         "../node_modules/primeui/primeui-ng-all.min.css",
         "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"
      ]
```

I was missing font-awesome.min.css in angular-cli.json file. 
Another point to remember is when you make change to angular-cli.json file styles section, always re run the "ng serve" command otherwise new styles will not show up.